# Are published sports results copyrightable?

Tags: copyright

In *[NBA vs. Motorola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Basketball_Ass%27n_v._Motorola,_Inc.)* where Motorola did not infringe NBA's copyright by publishing scores of games. However, I am wondering if published scores are copyrightable.

For instance, the result "Bulls 99-89 Lakers" itself may not be copyrightable (since it's a fact), but what if it is published on the NBA website? If I want to use the score that is published on the NBA website (without reaching an agreement with NBA), would I infringe NBA's copyright in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact is not copyright: the method of presentation (font, colour, logos etc.) is.

Comment: Additionally, some jurisdictions have database rights. Copying one result may not infringe copyright, but copying a whole database of results may.